# Jquery Vallenato 1.0 accordion plugin

Tags: jquery, accordion

Can someone please show me how to make the first accordion not open on page load with Jquery Vallenato?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

//Set The Accordion Content Width
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

// The Accordion Effect
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }

    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
});

return false;
});
```

http://www.switchroyale.com/vallenato/

Answer (score 1):

Comment out this section, like so:

```
//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
//$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
//$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
```